# Подогнать текст по ширине QLabel в pyqt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qss, qlabel

Как можно растянуть текст по всей ширине `QLabel`?

Через `self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignJustify)` происходит подгон `QLabel` под содержимое текста, мне нужно наоборот.

В **`css`** есть такая возможность - это `text-align: justify`, но, наверное, через **`css`** в *PyQt5* это не сделать, у меня не вышло.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class Ui_Form0(object):
    def setupUi0(self, Form0):
        Form0.setObjectName("Form0")
        Form0.setFixedSize(500, 300)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form0)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 500, 50))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("text-align: justify;")
        self.retranslateUi(Form0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form0)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form0):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form0.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form0", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form0",
                                      "Сообщество здесь, чтобы помочь вам с конкретными проблемами по программированию"))


class MenuWindow(QWidget, Ui_Form0):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi0(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui0 = MenuWindow()
    ui0.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текстовая строка должна интерпретируется как строка с форматированным текстом:

```
self.label_justify.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)
```

`label_justify` должна содержат политику переноса слов:

```
self.label_justify.setWordWrap(True)
```

Текстовая строка должна быть длиннее чем ширина виджета:

```
+ "&nbsp;" * 77
```

`label_justify` должна содержат свойство выравнивания содержимого метки:

```
self.label_justify.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignJustify)
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Form0(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form0):
        Form0.setObjectName("Form0")
        Form0.setFixedSize(600, 300)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form0)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 600, 50))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("text-align: justify;")
        self.retranslateUi(Form0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form0)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form0):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form0.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form0", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form0",
            "Сообщество здесь, чтобы помочь вам с конкретными проблемами "
            "по программированию."))


class MenuWindow(QWidget, Ui_Form0):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.label.setText(
            "Сообщество здесь, чтобы помочь вам с конкретными проблемами "
            "по программированию. " + " "*77
        )
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setAlignment(
            QtCore.Qt.AlignJustify | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter
        )
        self.label.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #3B0000;
            color: #fff;
        """)        

# !!! +++  v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^v^

        self.label_justify = QLabel(self)
        self.label_justify.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 125, 600, 50))
        self.label_justify.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)                      # !!!
        self.label_justify.setText(
            "Сообщество здесь, чтобы помочь вам с конкретными проблемами "
            "по программированию! " + "&nbsp;"*77 
        ) #                        --> ^^^^^^ <--                          # !!!
        
        self.label_justify.setWordWrap(True)                               # !!!
        self.label_justify.setAlignment(                                   # !!!
            QtCore.Qt.AlignJustify  | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter               # !!!
        )
        self.label_justify.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #3B0000;
            padding-top: 10px;                                    /* <---- +++ */  
            color: #fff;
        """)        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui0 = MenuWindow()
    ui0.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @dutik что не так?

Comment: Спасибо, Николай! Заработало, пытался разобраться с многострочным текстом.

Comment: Спасибо за метод, я не ожидал, что решение будет таким большим! Но всё работает! Как всегда вы помогли на высшем уровне!

Comment: @dutik пожалуйста.